# Is there a quick way to check is S3 Server Access Logging is working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I've enabled Server Access Logging on some S3 buckets in CloudFormation templates and can see these changes reflected in the AWS Console. I would like to verify that everything is working as intended and see some access logs in the target bucket. Is there something that can be done that would create a log to appear in the target bucket?

Answer (score 1):

It can take several hours for logs to appear. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html#server-access-logging-overview):

> Most log records are delivered within a **few hours** of the time that they are recorded, but they can be delivered more frequently.

So once you enable it, do some actions on your object, have to wait a bit. Its **not something you can control**. Its up to AWS. Though from my experience, I never had to wait hours for first log to appear.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Amazon S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html#how-logs-delivered)

> Server access log records are delivered on a best effort basis. Most requests for a bucket that is properly configured for logging result in a delivered log record. Most log records are delivered within a few hours of the time that they are recorded, but they can be delivered more frequently.

Do some get requests and then within a few hours you should have some logs.

The logs are more for a general overview of traffic, not near real-time.

> The purpose of server logs is to give you an idea of the nature of traffic against your bucket. It is rare to lose log records, but server logging is not meant to be a complete accounting of all requests.

Comment: Just to clarify run `aws s3api list-buckets` then wait?

Comment: Hi, try and access a object in the browser. Thats what this access logging provides. If you're looking for API calls you want to look at CloudTrail.